# Retrieve Channels-Tab from YouTube Channel via YouTube-API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As you may know some Content-Creators on YouTube not only got one Channel. Some Channels have a *Channel-Tab* where you can see the other channels hosted by the creator. I would like to get these channels, but unfortunately the YouTube-API can't retrieve the data via `channels: list`. Is there a parameter or another function how I can get this information?

Channel example: https://www.youtube.com/c/DunklerParabelritter/channels

Thank you in advance,

Aaron!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that once again [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) doesn't provide a basic feature.

I would recommend you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/02c2f0f61f02d3de9e6af78ace4a62d3f2e02b19/channels.php#L234-L310) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by requesting the JSON document https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=channels&id=CHANNEL_ID the data you are looking for are in `item["channelSections"]`.

Note that the channel id associated to [the channel you shared](https://www.youtube.com/c/DunklerParabelritter/channels) is [`UCK4LDHLxBqiAtcwCm4z7DRg`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCK4LDHLxBqiAtcwCm4z7DRg/channels), so you would obtain:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UCK4LDHLxBqiAtcwCm4z7DRg",
            "channelSections": [
                {
                    "title": "Mit Empfehlung des Dunklen!",
                    "sectionChannels": [
                        {
                            "channelId": "UCWZu-P34DVZUVrYAROU3Cmw",
                            "title": "Prinz",
                            "thumbnails": [
                                {
                                    "url": "https:\/\/yt3.googleusercontent.com\/knQfgyidSRlVLQfAw64R9DFWmnQt3BwdJUaRW1zHEVRgLswRcR9lsan_S4tGe4BfYJyo9Jppbg=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-mo",
                                    "width": 48,
                                    "height": 48
                                },
                                ...
                            ],
                            "videoCount": 128,
                            "subscriberCount": 111000
                        },
                        ...
                    ],
                    "nextPageToken": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```